# Does the DNS belong to the threat model in the ACME protocol with the TLS challenge

Tags: tls, acme

If I use the ACME protocol to generate Certificates and I use the [TLS Challenge](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8737), is the DNS Server a critical part in the threat model?

Comment: If an attacker is able to control the authoritative DNS for a domain that he/she does not own, then: he/she could create a private key, then exploit the DNS attack and use ACME protocol to cause a widely-trusted CA to issue a cert for that domain with a corresponding public key.  But, this attack is not specific to ACME protocol - the same attack would work with other types of [domain validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-validated_certificate) as well.